# UseState() returns correct value in useEffect() but nothing inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a problem with the following code:

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect: " + selectedItem)
}, [selectedItem])

const myFunc = () => {
    console.log(selectedItem)
    setSelectedItem("2")
    console.log(selectedItem)
}
```

What happens, is that I update the `SelectedItem()` in `myFunc`. In the `useEffect()` loop `selectedItem` prints correctly. But within `myFunc` I keep getting an empty string (The initial state), no matter how many times I trigger the function.

My code is relatively complex - In general it includes a couple of DOM updates, because I'm recursively building a treeview with unordered lists.

The `myFunc` is triggered when clicking on one of the `<li>` elements - But could that cause the rather strange behaviour of the `UseState()` ?

I am aware that `useState()` can be said to be somewhat an asynchronous function - But this may not be the problem here, since triggering the function multiple times still does print "".

Comment: Could you please provide more context?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't see what happens to `myFunc` between it being defined and it being called. Probably you wrap it in a closure somewhere.

Comment: "My code is relatively complex - In general it includes a couple of DOM updates, because I'm recursively building a treeview with unordered lists." — This is probably the problem. You should be able to build the treeview the React way and not use direct DOM.

Comment: Your example as a standalone does not have this problem. You need to provide more context, ideally a minimal reproducible example

Comment: The `console.log(selectedItem)` will have the value of `selectedItem` for whatever it was when it was closed over in callback scope. The `setSelectedItem("2")` update will still be enqueued however. And because of the way asynchronously processes state updates, the second `console.log(selectedItem)` can, and will, only ever log the same value it did 2 lines above.